# Flutter: Animate widget position and size to match another widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Im trying to build a tabs menu widget that contains an indicator that goes on top of the selected item, matching its size.

[image: tabs]

My first thought was to have a Stack with a row of items and an AnimatedPositioned indicator on top. However, I dont seem to find a way to get the selected item’s offset or size.

I also tried using an animated Transform widget but, alas, same issue getting the transform of the items to animate the indicator appropriately.

Could someone direct me to a widget or approach more suited to what I’m trying to accomplish?

Thanks in advance!